# Current draw of small TFT display

Tags: display

Has anyone used these small 1" displays before with a GC9A01A driver? [Link](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.28inch_LCD_Module)
I would like to use it for a battery powered project but am unable to find info about how much current it draws. I'd imagine there will be a large range depending on brightness level and how many pixels are illuminated. But does anyone have a ballpark number? Is 50mA enough to budget for it, 100mA? The datasheet was no help.

[image]

Comment: `Has anyone used?` and `Does anyone have?` are not electronics related questions

Comment: But asking about the current draw of a display is an electronics related question. Are you saying I should reword the question without the "has anyone used?"

Comment: yes ... this site is for preservation of questions and answers for future research about electronic design ... `has anyone used?` is a `yes/no` poll type question that is off topic here ... please ask about the problem, not about people encountering the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search finds a similar unit with 20mA claimed typical draw.

Chances are pretty good that it's in the 10-40mA range, given the FAQ number mentioned above, when operated with reasonable backlight intensity.

TFT draw is going to be dominated by the backlight with a relatively small current for the display itself and drivers that won't change much with the content displayed. Unlike OLED displays.

Answer (score 1):

If you click your link and scroll to the FAQ section, you will find the answer is there : 3.3V 31.2mA.

Now whether that is correct or not, is unknown.